# Python convert timestampMS to date

Tags: python, date, timestamp

using python 2.7 I have timestampMS ex: `timestampMs 1478001612891`

I want to convert it to a date format.

I have tried `datetime.fromtimestamp(int('1478013706323'))`

but get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime.fromtimestamp` expects input in seconds. Divide your number by `1000.0` before passing it in.

(From the specifications: `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)` will `return the local date corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by time.time()`. And `time.time()` will `return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number`.)

Comment: okay so that worked. but what do these numbers stand for in order? datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 11, 21, 46)

Comment: From the docs, the parameters are `year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None`.

Comment: great thanks, il accept your answer in a few minutes!